# Dynamic tree structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For my application i need to create one tree structure which consist of nested folder which will grow depends open server reponse.
just like an email has tree structure-

```
inbox or sent or draft or outbox(f)/a(f)/some content 
inbox or sent or draft or outbox(f)/a(f)/b(f)/email  content
inbox or sent or draft or outbox(f)/email  content
```

and other possible combination.
since  i will get this path from the server so i have to loop it and create appropriate structure..can you guys please help me in it..
thanks in advance.

Comment: the only problem which i m facing is to create <ul><li> structure using above posted content.because we have to take care of parentnode ,childNodes and subChildNodes.

Comment: I fail to see the tree in your question. Can you explain more?

Comment: you have seen the any email tree..
inbox
  ---->folder
         ------>abhimanyu

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be considerably easier to do cross browser using a JavaScript framework (I know this appears to be a standard answer at the moment, but it is a good answer in this case)... use jQuery!

There is a [treeview plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview) that does exactly what you need, with lots of options too.

Comment: the only problem which i m facing is to create <ul><li> structure using above posted content.